# How to make a UITable to highlight its 5th row when we start the app?

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using a splitviewcontroller. When I select something in the table the row is highlighted and it is shown in the detailed view. I have also provided an option to change the contents in the detailed view by scrolling.

When I start I want the the 5th row to be highlighted by itself, how can I do it?

Comment: Row highlighting should be transient. Apple has said it is a HIG violation to leave a row highlighted after the user has touched it (you need to use something like the checkmark accessory view to indicate selection instead), so proceed with caution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following UITableView method:

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition;
```

Comment: Ya, I was trying to make it call somehow. Wrote it inside the viewDidLoad like this. But its crashing.

 NSIndexPath *scrollIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:0];
 [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

I was using the above function from the start. But the app was crashing when I wrote this code into the viewDidLoad.

```
NSIndexPath *scrollIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:0];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

There is no data loaded into the UITableView instance. You can't select a row that doesn't exist. This was the reason it was crashing. And yes, this is the function that will help us do it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the data is not yet loaded into the table view, there is no cell at index path (5,0).

Try calling it inside `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;` instead, it should work.